# Mosaic rasters and clip

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic

I have a number of satellite image rasters covering my study area. I want to mosaic and clip the output raster to my study area. Note that the images overlap each other and do not join end to end. How can I perform this task?

Comment: Are you familiar with Mosaic to New Raster?: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm How do you intend to use the mosaic?

Comment: Thanks, this tool is useful and I set my study area in environment settings.